# Edit data from a pyqt6 Table widget cell and save to database

Tags: pyqt6

I'm trying to edit a cell in a Table Widget in Pyqt6, and save this new value in the database. I can get the value of the cell, the row and the column, but when it comes to saving it in the bank I get stuck. My code:

```
def update_data(self):
        selected_row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        selected_column = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        new_value = self.edit_line.text()

        if selected_row != -1 and selected_column != -1:
        # Obter o valor da célula selecionada
            current_value = self.tableWidget.item(selected_row, selected_column).text()
            print(current_value)
            print(selected_column)
        # Implementar a lógica para atualizar o banco de dados
            cursor = db.cnxn.cursor()
            headers = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
            query = f"UPDATE CONTROLE_DIFAL SET {headers[selected_column]} = ? WHERE ID = ?"
            cursor.execute(query, (new_value, current_value))
            cursor.commit()
```

O código de erro gerado é esse:

```
File "c:\Users\INFORMATICA\ImportPyqt\main.py", line 69, in update_data

    cursor.execute(query, (new_value, current_value))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'ID'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

I want to edit the data in the Table Widget cell and have this edit saved in the SQL Server database.